GUI mode veracrypt does not ask for root password when launched from command line
When I launch veracrypt using applications menu and mount, it asks for root password. However when I run veracrypt (GUI mode) through command line, it gives the error
Permission Denied
/media/veracrypt10

VeraCrypt::Directory::Create:29

If I do sudo veracrypt, it works though.
System Information:
OS - Debian GNU/Linux 12 (bookworm)
Veracrypt - 1.26.7

